# SSIS package with Oracle Connection Attunity: The ORACLE registry key cannot be opened

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl, attunity

Please could someone help me on similar/same issue as in this [TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141298/problem-trying-to-run-ssis-package-with-oracle-connection-attunity/65008233#65008233) - SSIS package that connects to an oracle DB using Attunity Connection Manager

My environment situation is:

- DEV Virtual Machine: VS2019 Version 16.8.1 (Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer Version 15.0.2000.132)
- DEV SQL Sever: 2017 DEV (Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU22) (KB4577467) - 14.0.3356.20 (X64))

I have installed:

- [LINK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55179) Microsoft Connectors v5.0 for Oracle and Teradata ATTUNITY
  (as i need SQL 2017 compatibility)

and

- [LINK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58228) Microsoft Connector for Oracle V1.0

(I have tried multiple time installing only 32 or only 64 versions, and uninstalling and restarting VMs)
I have SSIS package with Oracle Connection Manager.
In Visual Studio inside package:

- IF SQL Target version is SQL 2019

1. Connection manager to oracle test: **SUCCESS**
2. Run Package: **SUCCESS**
3. Deply Package to SSIS DB: **Fail** (Reasonable -> I have SQL 2017 :)

---

1. IF SQL Target version is SQL 2017
2. Connection manager to oracle test: **SUCCESS**
3. Run Package: **FAIL**

   ERROR in DEBUG MODE:

> [OMS OrderLines ABBICS V_F_ORDERS_RO24881SRU [3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58228)] Error: The
> AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager Oracle DB
> failed with error code 0x80004005.  There may be error messages posted
> before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method
> call failed.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: OMS OrderLines ABBICS V_F_ORDERS_RO24881SRU
> failed validation and returned error code 0x80004005.
>
> **Error: The ORACLE registry key cannot be opened. Verify that the Oracle Client for Windows x86 is installed properly.**

4. Deply Package to SSIS DB: **SUCCESS**
5. Run Package on SQL Server (from SSIS Catalog or from JOB):  **FAIL** -> Basically same errors as in package

I have tried running packages in 64 and 32 bit mode as well as running job in 32 bit mode. The only difference was

> ...Windows x86 is installed properly...

or

> ...Windows x64 is installed properly...

Thank you!
Wojciech

Comment: Maybe someone can share registry keys that should be created during installation process?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I was able to solve that uninstalling everything and install what i mentioned in post above plus:

32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio

ODAC 12.2c Release 1 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.2.0.1.1)

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-utilsoft-downloads.html

This fixed issue and package can be run in both 32 and 64 bit mode

- The only question that remains, do i really need to install this whole package with unnecessary (for me) features? Now i have to install it on all DEV/UAT/PROD nodes :/ Is there any particular component I can install to get this up and running?

**EDIT:** To minimize installation components - >On machines with SQL server 2017 I did following things:

1. Downloaded 64-bit ODAC 12.2c Release 1 (12.2.0.1.0) Xcopy for Windows x64
   (ODAC122010Xcopy_x64.zip) from [LINK](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/odac-downloads.html)
2. Unzipped File on SQL VM
3. Run CMD as admin, navigate to unzipped location and run

> install.bat basic F:\ORACLE myhome false true

This will install Oracle Instant Client Machine Wide

4. Added to system variable **PATH** value: F:\ORACLE\

This allows me run SQL jobs successfully (remember to install other components mentioned in main post!)